# Perform two steps of the forward Euler method for the following system of first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'''(t)+sin(t)y''(t)-y'(t)+y(t) = 1$$

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = f(t,z)$$
Converting it to a system of first order differential equations:
$$x_1(t)=y(t)$$
$$x_2(t)=y'(t)$$
$$x_3(t)=y''(t)$$

so I can then do,
$$x_1'(t)=y'(t)$$
$$x_2'(t)=y''(t)$$
$$x_3'(t)=1-sin(t)x_3(t)+x_2(t)-x_1(t)$$

and I think the dynamics function is:

$$f(t,z) = [x_2(t), x_3(t), f(t)-sin(t)x_3(t)+g(t)x_2(t)-g(t)x_1(t)]$$

I am given initial values $t_0=0$, the vector $(1,1,1)$ and a step size of 0.5.

I know the formula for the forward Euler method is:
$$z_{n+1} = z_n+f(t,z_n)(t_{n+1}-t_n)$$
$$z_{1} = (1,1,1)+f(0.5,(1,1,1))(0.5)$$

I don't know how to compute $f(0.5,(1,1,1))$ since I don't know what $y'(t)$ is.

Any help would really be appreciated!